# Assumptions and strengths and weaknesses of a mathematical model

Tags: graphing-functions, conic-sections

The assignment task is about finding out the volumes and surface area of the satellite dish in the movie "Golden Eye", using solids of revolution.

1. This question is about finding the surface area of the dish so that the cost of paint required to recoat the dish can be calculated. What can be some assumptions?
2. This question is about finding two alternate shapes that can be stored underground to contain the rainwater collected in the dish. Both has to be able to contain the same amount of water. One of them has to be a paraboloid. I decided to use a thin paraboloid and a wide one. What can be some strength & weaknesses for each model (easier/harder to clean etc.)? What can be some assumptions for this question?

I am really stuck and I can't think of anything. Would appreciate any suggestions! Thanks:)

Comment: Glib answer: the dish pictured in the movie is the [Arecibo Observatory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arecibo_Observatory). A bit of googling will give the area =P

Comment: Didn't you see my analysis in your post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2280171/which-paraboloid-would-have-a-larger-surface-area-or-would-they-be-the-same/2280837#2280837?